# Node.js bulk download and Bluebird promises

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm writing a bulk downloader for node.js and trying to understand bluebird promises.
I want to limit the number of parallel requests and disk writes.
As I understand it, `Promise.map()` with `{concurrent: }` should do what I want.

Because `pipe()` and `http.get()` can't automatically be promisified, I'm trying to use custom promises.

But I don't fully understand the `then()` mechanism.
To me, it sounds like the returned promise should only be fulfilled when the whole chain has been fulfilled.

However, in my code only the first promise in the chain appears to be waited for by `map()`, and many request and disk writes happen in parallel.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';

Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
Promise.map(Images, image => {
        console.log("Opening image " + image.id);
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/' + image.id + '.jpg');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              console.log("Downloading image " + image.id);
              https.get(image.url, resolve).on("error", reject);
          })
          .then(response => {
              response.pipe(file);
              console.log("Saving image " + image.id);
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  file.on("finish", resolve);
                  file.on("error", reject);
              });
          })
          .then(() => {
              console.log("Finished writing image " + image.id);
              file.close();
          })
          .catch(e => {
              console.log("Error during image save of " + image.id + ": " + e.code)
          });
    }, {concurrent: 50})
      .then(res => {
          console.log("Finished writing all images")
      })
      .catch(e => {
          console.log("Some images failed to be written: " + e.code)
      });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me understand the flow of promise fulfillment and rejection?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. Are you saying that there are *more* than 50 downloads+diskwrites happening concurrently? Can you post the resulting log (maybe with a downscaled example, 10 files with concurrency of 5), please?

Comment: I figured it out. The keyword is `concurrency`  not `concurrent`. Fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand, you're trying to download multiple images with promise. Actually you don't need to promisify `fs`. You should use `request` module for easier downloading.

Here's a shortest working example I can come up with

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var images = [{
    url: 'http://bluebirdjs.com/img/logo.png',
    file_name: 'bluebird.png'
}, {
    url: 'http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png',
    file_name: 'ubuntu.png'
}, {
    url: 'https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/raspberry-pi-logo.png',
    file_name: 'raspberry-pi.png'
}];

// To Download Serially
Promise.each(images, image => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Downloading Image: ' + image.file_name);
    request(image.url).on('error', reject).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, image.file_name))).on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + image.file_name);
        resolve();
    });
})).then(() => {
    console.log('All Image Downloaded!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed: ' + err.message);
});

// To Download in Parallel (with 2 maximum concurrent jobs)
Promise.map(images, image => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Downloading Image: ' + image.file_name);
    request(image.url).on('error', reject).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, image.file_name))).on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + image.file_name);
        resolve();
    });
}), {
    concurrency: 2
}).then(() => {
    console.log('All Image Downloaded!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed: ' + err.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your implementation is indeed cleaner. I figured out my mistake; I wasn't using the right property in the option object for `Promise.map()`

Comment: By the way, I was promisifying `fs` for another section of code that I didn't include here.