# Nodejs: Error while downloading multiple files by looping through array of links

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var ultUrls = [{
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/kl44uq60z4631.png',
  name: 'pics/A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/9eocp20xr6631.jpg',
  name: 'pics/Athens at night.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/0gezn9zjr6631.jpg',
  name: 'pics/This is Rayne. Her favorite color is orange. Her job is a clown for the circus. Her motto is *honk honk*..jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/fxcivargr6631.png',
  name: 'pics/Reddit your input is greatly appreciated.png'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/xzpukskhr6631.jpg',
  name: 'pics/Cranberry lake Ontario.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/4mplt3joh5631.jpg',
  name: 'pics/Pics of insects are the best.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/03q4c5ndq6631.jpg',
  name: 'pics/Elvis Presley during his service in the U.S. Army.jpg'
}]
```

While downloading files in this array I'm getting ENONENT:no such file or directory, open ...

```
 var downloadImages = function(callback) {

    ultUrls.forEach( function(str) {

     download_file_httpget(str.url, str.name, function(){console.log('Finished Downloading' + filename)});
   });

 }
var download_file_httpget = function(url, dest, callback){

     request.get(url)
     .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
     .on('close', callback);

 };
```

**Tried with destination**

```
 var download_file_httpget = function(url, dest, callback){
     let destn = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\' + dest;
     request.get(url)
     .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destn))
     .on('close', callback);

 };
```

**UnCaught Exception: Error:ENONENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Downloads\pics\A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png**

Comment: You need to define the path to download into, not only the file's name (`str.name`). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753550/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Absolute path like C:/folder ?

Comment: Yes, please try this

Comment: I did. Same error. Please check my updated question

Comment: create `pics` folder in `C:\Users\Downloads` , then try again.

Comment: I did. Still getting the error.

Comment: @SaiKrishna, I disbelieve.  I think @hoangdv nailed it.  Unless you are getting the undefined `filename` error.  See my answer.

Comment: Did you run your code on `cmd` or `powershell`?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Just change the name attribute of each image by removing 'pics/'. It will work.

Here is the final code:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
var ultUrls = [ { url: 'https://i.redd.it/kl44uq60z4631.png', name: 'A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/9eocp20xr6631.jpg', name: 'Athens at night.jpg' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/0gezn9zjr6631.jpg', name: 'This is Rayne. Her favorite color is orange. Her job is a clown for the circus. Her motto is honk honk..jpg' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/fxcivargr6631.png', name: 'Reddit your input is greatly appreciated.png' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/xzpukskhr6631.jpg', name: 'Cranberry lake Ontario.jpg' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/4mplt3joh5631.jpg', name: 'Pics of insects are the best.jpg' }, { url: 'https://i.redd.it/03q4c5ndq6631.jpg', name: 'Elvis Presley during his service in the U.S. Army.jpg' } ]

var downloadImages = function(callback) {

    ultUrls.forEach( function(str) {

     download_file_httpget(str.url, str.name, function(){console.log('Finished Downloading' + str.name)});
   });

 }

 var download_file_httpget = function(url, dest, callback){
     let destn = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\pics\\' + dest;
     request.get(url)
     .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destn))
     .on('close', callback);

 };

 downloadImages();
```

As pointed out by @hoangdv create a pics folder and also remove `'pics/'` from str.name that is being passed to `download_file_httpget`

Comment: I don't think that there would be any problem passing `destn` to `fs.createWriteStream`.  It looks fine to me.  Why do you think that the variable is not getting passed?

Comment: Also check to see if the destination path that you have specified before str.name is created already. I think that Downloads folder may not be created.

Comment: You can use [`fs-extra.ensureDir`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) to create the dir if you want, too.

Answer (score 0):

This complete example works correctly, **provided that you create a folder called** `pics`.

You'll need to install the *request* module first too.

```
npm install request --save
```

I didn't change much except:

1. formatted the `ultUrls` declaration
2. replaced the code `+ filename` with `+ str.name` because `filename` was undefined.

Here's the code:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var ultUrls = [
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/kl44uq60z4631.png', name: 'pics/A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/9eocp20xr6631.jpg', name: 'pics/Athens at night.jpg' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/0gezn9zjr6631.jpg', name: 'pics/This is Rayne. Her favorite color is orange. Her job is a clown for the circus. Her motto is honk honk..jpg' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/fxcivargr6631.png', name: 'pics/Reddit your input is greatly appreciated.png' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/xzpukskhr6631.jpg', name: 'pics/Cranberry lake Ontario.jpg' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/4mplt3joh5631.jpg', name: 'pics/Pics of insects are the best.jpg' },
  { url: 'https://i.redd.it/03q4c5ndq6631.jpg', name: 'pics/Elvis Presley during his service in the U.S. Army.jpg' }
];

var downloadImages = function (callback) {
  ultUrls.forEach(function (str) {
    download_file_httpget(str.url, str.name, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + str.name) });
  });

}
var download_file_httpget = function (url, dest, callback) {

  request.get(url)
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
    .on('close', callback);

};

downloadImages();
```

Comment: copy pasted your code. Still getting the same error. wth

Comment: installed request too

Comment: Is there any other way to download multiple files?

Comment: I don't believe I'm getting an accurate report from you.  If you got `UnCaught Exception: Error:ENONENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Downloads\pics\A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png` running this code, then it's because `C:\Users\Downloads\pics` doesn't exist.  If you got it running this code then you've also set your current working directory to `C:\Users\Downloads` already, which is weird. Can you cut and paste the actual error you got? As it stands, so many of us are convinced that you just need to create the pics directory properly - I still am.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I deleted the 'pics' part from the url. This was also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666258/7599905

Comment: So what is your current status?  Did you solve your problem?  Is your original question answered?

Comment: Yes. I've answered my question with the solution. Thank you for you help. I need to learn more about Async and Promises

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing '/pics' from the url.

```
var ultUrls = [{
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/kl44uq60z4631.png',
  name: 'A bison in steam during winter at Yellowstone National Park.png'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/9eocp20xr6631.jpg',
  name: 'Athens at night.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/0gezn9zjr6631.jpg',
  name: 'This is Rayne. Her favorite color is orange. Her job is a clown for the circus. Her motto is *honk honk*..jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/fxcivargr6631.png',
  name: 'pics/Reddit your input is greatly appreciated.png'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/xzpukskhr6631.jpg',
  name: 'Cranberry lake Ontario.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/4mplt3joh5631.jpg',
  name: 'Pics of insects are the best.jpg'
}, {
  url: 'https://i.redd.it/03q4c5ndq6631.jpg',
  name: 'Elvis Presley during his service in the U.S. Army.jpg'
}]
```

Then used promise like so

```
Promise.each(ultUrls, url=> new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Downloading Image: ' + url.file_name);
    request(url.url).on('error', reject).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, url.file_name))).on('finish', () => {
        console.log('Downloaded Image: ' + url.file_name);
        resolve();
    });
})).then(() => {
    console.log('All Image Downloaded!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed: ' + err.message);
});
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666258/7599905

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't create the `pics` directory before

Comment: This belongs in the comments.